# Cannot give access for a PC2 using PC1 SSH keys to a Git repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've a PC1 with access (The command `$ git clone` works fine) to a repository using SSH connection. I tried to give access to a PC2 for this reposity too, so i've done a copy of the keys `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` from PC1 to my PC2 `~/.ssh` folder for give access for this computer too, but it's not working. It's ask me for a password which i don't have, this is what happened on PC2:

```
$ git clone git@repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
git@repo's password:
```

What i've to do to give access for this repository using the PC1 keys on PC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem doing this:

First, copied the PC1 keys into PC2 SSH folder:

```
$ mv pc1Key pc1Key.pub ~/.ssh/
```

After copied my keys from PC1 to PC2, i've changed the keys permission:

```
$ chmod 400 ~/.ssh/pc1Key
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/pc1Key.pub
```

And then, loaded my keys into my SSH agent:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/pc1Key
```

NOTE: The argument `~/.ssh/pc1Key` is necessary only if the key does not have the default filename, if the keys are `id_rsa` named, you will just execut `$ ssh-add`.

Reference: https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign/